# Getting current URL without using Preact-Router

Tags: preact

I'm building a widget.

I read it somewhere

"not to use preact-router, because it adds event listeners to all anchors on document level, which is not acceptable for a widget (remember not to mess with the hosting page)".

I want to just get the current URL and no other data is required. How can it be achieved?

P.S: I'm new to programming. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is the current URL then `window.location` does the trick.

Comment: window.location.href right?
I'm seeing many stuff like orgin, host etc

Comment: Depends entirely on what you're looking for, as you haven't said. All URL data is in that object. Yes, `window.location.href` can be what you want if you need the entire URL. If you just want a part of it then maybe `window.location.origin` or `.pathname` fits your needs better. Either way, it's all there on that object.